# Disable click-through on windows

Tags: windows, windows-10, user-interface

Is there a way to disable click-through in Windows 10? Click-through being when you click on a button in an inactive window, it makes the window active and also triggers the button. I'd rather it just make the window active.

Comment: The behavior you describe has been the behavior of a Win32 since at least Windows XP.

Comment: @Ramhound OK, but I'm asking if there's a way to change it.